# Add event listener to a child object of the window

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to add an event to a child object on the window, one that will accept events from anywhere (like the window)?

So, for example:

```
window.myVariable.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown);
```

This way I can remove this particular key down event, without removing other keydown events that are attached to the window.

How is something like this done?

Comment: What is this `myVariable`? Who will fire this `keydown` event?

Comment: `myVariable` could be anything. I think basically I want to make a wrapper for particular events that I can then loop through and remove them

Comment: So it will be up to your app to fire these events (as opposed to the browser, like with `onclick`)?

Comment: I have an `Editor` and an `Engine`, I would like to place the `Editor` events in one object and the `Engine` events in another so I can enable/disable them whenever I please. They both can have the same event type such as `keydown` on the window, so removing them would remove both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple registry that operates on a "namespace".

```js
(function() {

  var register = {};

  function addNamedListener(namespace, eventType, callback) {
    register[namespace] = register[namespace] || [];
    register[namespace].push({
      eventType: eventType,
      callback: callback
    });

    window.addEventListener(eventType, callback);
  }

  function removeNamedListener(namespace) {
    register[namespace].forEach(function(event) {
      window.removeEventListener(event.eventType, event.callback);
    });
  }

  window.WindowEvents = {
    addNamedListener: addNamedListener,
    removeNamedListener: removeNamedListener
  }

})();

// Attach a general window event to the actual window
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});

// Attach a namedspaced event
WindowEvents.addNamedListener('windowClicks', 'click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});

// Attach another event to the same namespace
WindowEvents.addNamedListener('windowClicks', 'click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.clientX);
});

// Attach a new event to a different namespace
WindowEvents.addNamedListener('down', 'mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log('Mouse down occurred');
});
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
```

Then, when you are ready to get rid of the events in that "namespace", you would just do this:

```
WindowEvents.removeNamedListener('windowClicks');
```

This will leave the original window events, as well as the other namespace event that was created (`down`).

This should at least get you started.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar. I created 2 classes one to manage the events with an array of events, and one that holds information about an event (which gets added to the array). I then can add items to the array, then loop through the array to remove the event.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, although you could assign the handler to, for example, the body element.

> This way I can remove this particular key down event, without removing other keydown events that are attached to the window.

This sounds like an X-Y problem though.

[`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) requires that you specify *which* event listener you are going to remove.

```
removeEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown);
```

… so the default behaviour is "without removing other keydown events".